# I catch exception JpaSystemException - identifier of an instance then update category field, but marked up the scheme correct

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

Then update category field in billboard, i catch exception from JPA

> "JpaSystemException"  "identifier of an instance of
> ru.rshbintech.crft.cos.billboard.dao.entities.Category was altered
> from 1 to 3; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
> identifier of an instance of
> ru.rshbintech.crft.cos.billboard.dao.entities.Category was altered
> from 1 to 3"

This is Billboard entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "billboard")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Billboard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "offer_type", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private OfferType offerType;

    @Column(name = "author", nullable = false)
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "created")
    private Instant created;

    @Column(name = "cover_id")
    private Long coverId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status_billboard")
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private Long cityId;
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        created = created == null ? Instant.now() : created;
    }
}
```

And This is Category entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "dict_categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Billboard> billboards = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Category parent;

    @Column(name = "category_level", nullable = false)
    private Integer categoryLevel;

}
```

And add Service class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class BillBoardService {
    private final BillboardRepository repository;
    private final BillBoardMapper mapper;
    private final UserInfo userInfo;
    private final StorageService storageService;
    private final BillBoardMergeMapper billBoardMergeMapper;

    private final BillboardStatusRepository statusRepository;

    @Qualifier("userDtoConverter")
    private final Converter<EmployeeDto, UserDto> userDtoConverter;

    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    private static final String NOT_FOUND_AUTHOR_MESSAGE = "Authors not found";

    public BillBoardService(BillboardRepository repository, BillBoardMapper mapper, UserInfo userInfo, StorageService storageService, BillBoardMergeMapper billBoardMergeMapper, BillboardStatusRepository statusRepository, Converter<EmployeeDto, UserDto> userDtoConverter, CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
        this.storageService = storageService;
        this.billBoardMergeMapper = billBoardMergeMapper;
        this.statusRepository = statusRepository;
        this.userDtoConverter = userDtoConverter;
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLException.class)
    public BillboardDtoResponse save(BillboardDtoRequest billboardDto, TokenDto tokenDto) throws NotFoundException {

        EmployeeDto employeeDto;
        try {
            Mono<List<EmployeeDto>> mono = userInfo.getUsersInfo(List.of(tokenDto.getUpn()), tokenDto.getTokenBody());
            List<EmployeeDto> employeeDtos = mono.block();
            if (employeeDtos == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException(NOT_FOUND_AUTHOR_MESSAGE +  billboardDto.getAuthor());
            }
            employeeDto = employeeDtos.get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(LoggerMessages.ERROR_GET_INFO_USER, tokenDto.getUpn(), e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }


        Billboard billboard = mapper.billboardDtoRequestToBillboard(billboardDto);
        billboard.setCityId(billboardDto.getCity().getId());
        billboard.setAuthor(tokenDto.getUpn());

        try {
            billboard = repository.save(billboard);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(LoggerMessages.ERROR_GET_DATA_FROM_DB, e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
            throw e;
        }

        BillboardDtoResponse dto = mapper.billboardToBillboardDtoResponse(billboard);
        CityDto cityDto = new CityDto();
        cityDto.setId(billboard.getCityId());
        dto.setCity(cityDto);
        this.addCityIfExists(billboardDto, tokenDto);

        UserDto userDto = this.userDtoConverter.map(employeeDto);
        dto.setAuthor(userDto);
        return dto;

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public BillboardDtoResponse getBillboardBy(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull TokenDto tokenDto) throws NotFoundException, IOException {
        Optional<Billboard> maybeBillboard = repository.findById(id);
        if(maybeBillboard.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("billboard with id" + id + " not exists");
        }
        Billboard billboard = maybeBillboard.get();
        BillboardDtoResponse billboardDto = mapper.billboardToBillboardDtoResponse(billboard);
        EmployeeDto employeeDto;
        Mono<List<EmployeeDto>> mono = userInfo.getUsersInfo(List.of(billboard.getAuthor()), tokenDto.getTokenBody());
        List<EmployeeDto> employeeDtos = mono.block();
        if (employeeDtos == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException(NOT_FOUND_AUTHOR_MESSAGE + billboardDto.getAuthor());
        }

        employeeDto = employeeDtos.get(0);
        UserDto userDto = this.userDtoConverter.map(employeeDto);
        billboardDto.setAuthor(userDto);
        CityDto cityDto = new CityDto();
        cityDto.setId(billboard.getCityId());
        billboardDto.setCity(cityDto);
        this.addCityIfExists(billboardDto, tokenDto);

        try {
            FileRecordRequestSearchDto searchDto = this.buildSearchFileDto(billboard.getId());
            List<FileRecordResponseDto> responseDtos = storageService.search(searchDto);
            if (responseDtos != null) {
                this.orderListOfImagesByCover(responseDtos, billboardDto.getCoverId());
                billboardDto.setBillboardFiles(responseDtos);
            }
            return billboardDto;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(LoggerMessages.ERROR_GET_FILES_INFO, tokenDto.getUpn(), e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLException.class)
    public BillboardDto update(@NotNull BillboardDto billboardDto, TokenDto tokenDto) throws IOException, NotFoundException {
        Optional<Billboard> maybeBillboard = repository.findById(billboardDto.getId());
        if (maybeBillboard.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Billboard with id " + billboardDto.getId() + " not found");
        }
        Billboard billboardFromDB = maybeBillboard.get();
        billBoardMergeMapper.mergeNonNullFields(billboardDto, billboardFromDB);
        if (billboardDto.getCity() != null) {
            billboardFromDB.setCityId(billboardDto.getCity().getId());
        }

        Billboard billboard = repository.save(billboardFromDB);
        BillboardDto dto = mapper.billboardToBillboardDto(billboard);
        CityDto cityDto = new CityDto();
        cityDto.setId(billboard.getCityId());
        dto.setCity(cityDto);
        Mono<List<EmployeeDto>> mono = userInfo.getUsersInfo(List.of(billboard.getAuthor()), tokenDto.getTokenBody());
        List<EmployeeDto> employeeDtos = mono.block();
        if (Objects.isNull(employeeDtos)) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Users for billboard with id " + dto.getId() + " not found");
        }
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = employeeDtos.get(0);
        UserDto userDto = this.userDtoConverter.map(employeeDto);
        dto.setAuthor(userDto);
        this.addCityIfExists(dto, tokenDto);

        FileRecordRequestSearchDto searchDto = this.buildSearchFileDto(billboard.getId());
        List<FileRecordResponseDto> responseDtos = storageService.search(searchDto);
        dto.setBillboardFiles(responseDtos);

        return dto;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Response<List<BillboardDto>> search(SearchRequest request, TokenDto tokenDto) throws IOException, NotFoundException {
        SearchSpecification<Billboard> specification = new SearchSpecification<>(request);
        Pageable pageable = SearchSpecification.getPageable(request.getPage(), request.getSize());
        Page<Billboard> page = repository.findAll(specification, pageable);
        List<Billboard> billboards = page.getContent();
        if (billboards.isEmpty()) {
            List<Billboard> emptyBillboards = new ArrayList<>();
            buildResponse(emptyBillboards, 0, 0, request.getPage(), request.getSize());
        }
        List<BillboardDto> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> authors = billboards.stream().map(Billboard::getAuthor).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        try {
            Mono<List<EmployeeDto>> mono = userInfo.getUsersInfo(authors.stream().toList(), tokenDto.getTokenBody());
            List<EmployeeDto> employeeDtosList = mono.block();
            if (employeeDtosList == null || employeeDtosList.isEmpty()) {
                throw new NotFoundException(NOT_FOUND_AUTHOR_MESSAGE);
            }
            Map<String, EmployeeDto> upnToEmployee = employeeDtosList
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(EmployeeDto::getUserPrincipalName, employeeDto -> employeeDto));
            for(Billboard billboard : billboards) {
                BillboardDto billboardDto = mapper.billboardToBillboardDto(billboard);
                EmployeeDto employeeDto = upnToEmployee.get(billboard.getAuthor());
                UserDto userDto = this.userDtoConverter.map(employeeDto);
                billboardDto.setAuthor(userDto);
                CityDto cityDto = new CityDto();
                cityDto.setId(billboard.getCityId());
                billboardDto.setCity(cityDto);
                dtos.add(billboardDto);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(LoggerMessages.ERROR_GET_INFO_USER, tokenDto.getUpn(), e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }


        List<Long> billboardIds = billboards.stream().map(Billboard::getId).toList();
        try {
            List<FileRecordResponseDto> fileRecordResponseDtos = storageService.search(SystemParameters.OBJ_TYPE, billboardIds);
            if(!fileRecordResponseDtos.isEmpty()) {
                Map<Long, List<FileRecordResponseDto>> idsToFileResponseDto = this.collectFileDtoById(fileRecordResponseDtos);
                for (BillboardDto billboardDto : dtos) {
                    List<FileRecordResponseDto> fileResponseDto = idsToFileResponseDto.get(billboardDto.getId());
                    if (fileResponseDto != null && (!fileResponseDto.isEmpty())) {
                        fileResponseDto = this.orderListOfImagesByCover(fileResponseDto, billboardDto.getCoverId());
                        billboardDto.setBillboardFiles(fileResponseDto);
                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(LoggerMessages.ERROR_GET_FILES_INFO, tokenDto.getUpn(), e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        List<Long> citiesId = billboards.stream().map(Billboard::getCityId).distinct().toList();

        Mono<List<CityDto>> cities = userInfo.findCitiesByIds(tokenDto.getTokenBody(), citiesId);
        List<CityDto> cityDtos = cities.block();
        if (cityDtos == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Cities are not be got");
        }
        Map<Long, CityDto> idToCity = cityDtos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(CityDto::getId, Function.identity(),
                (existing, replacement) -> existing));
        dtos.forEach(billboardDto -> {
            CityDto cityDto = idToCity.get(billboardDto.getCity().getId());
            billboardDto.setCity(cityDto);
        });

        return buildResponse(dtos, page.getTotalPages(), page.getTotalElements(), page.getNumber(), page.getSize());
    }
    @Transactional
    public Status change(@NotNull Long id, TokenDto token, @NotNull BillboardAction action) throws NotFoundException, ActionNotExists, AuthentificationException {
        if (token == null) {
            throw new AuthentificationException("Authorization token is empty");
        }
        Optional<Billboard> opt = repository.findById(id);
        if (opt.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Billboard with id " + id + " is not present");
        }
        Billboard billboard = opt.get();
        BillboardStatus billboardStatus = statusRepository.findBillboardStatusByAction(action);
        if (billboardStatus == null) {
            throw new ActionNotExists("Action " + action + " not exists");
        }

        billboard.setStatus(billboardStatus.getNewStatus());
        return billboardStatus.getNewStatus();
    }

    private FileRecordRequestSearchDto buildSearchFileDto(Long billboardId) {
        return FileRecordRequestSearchDto
                .builder()
                .objId(billboardId)
                .objType(SystemParameters.OBJ_TYPE)
                .systemId(SystemParameters.SYSTEM_ID)
                .build();
    }

    private  Map<Long, List<FileRecordResponseDto>> collectFileDtoById(List<FileRecordResponseDto> fileRecordResponseDtos) {
        Map<Long, List<FileRecordResponseDto>> idsToFileResponseDto = new HashMap<>();
        for (FileRecordResponseDto responseFile : fileRecordResponseDtos) {
            Long objeId = responseFile.getObjId();
            if (!idsToFileResponseDto.containsKey(objeId)) {
                List<FileRecordResponseDto> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(responseFile);
                idsToFileResponseDto.put(objeId, list);
            } else {
                idsToFileResponseDto.get(objeId).add(responseFile);
            }
        }

        return idsToFileResponseDto;
    }


    private List<FileRecordResponseDto> orderListOfImagesByCover(List<FileRecordResponseDto> fileRecordResponseDtos, Long coverId) {
        List<FileRecordResponseDto> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        Optional<FileRecordResponseDto> coverImage = fileRecordResponseDtos.stream().filter( f -> f.getObjId().equals(coverId)).findFirst();
        coverImage.ifPresent(orderList::add);
        fileRecordResponseDtos.forEach(f -> {
            if (!f.getObjId().equals(coverId)) {
                orderList.add(f);
        }});
        return orderList;
    }

    private void addCityIfExists(ParentBillboard billboardDto, TokenDto tokenDto) throws NotFoundException {
        Mono<CityDto> cityDto = userInfo.findCityBy(tokenDto.getTokenBody(), billboardDto.getCity().getId());
        if (cityDto == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Not Found city with id " + billboardDto.getCity().getId());
        }
        billboardDto.setCity(cityDto.block());
    }
}
```

I Can't understand what wrong when i update?

Comment: You would need to add the service layer where you write your entities to your DB. The error message tells you that somehow you change the id of an already existing entity which was persisted in the DB.